# MySql constraint depending on condition

Tags: mysql, constraints, conditional-statements

In my `MySql-Database`i have three `tables` - `Battle`, `Group` and `Game`.

**Game-Table:**

[image]

Now i want to add a `constraint` to the `id` `column` which is no problem at all but i want it according to the value in the `objectType` `column`.

If the `objectType` is `battle` i want the `constraint` to `Battle`.`battleId` and if it's `group`i want the `constraint` to `Group`.`groupId`

Is that somehow possible or do i have to add a `column` for `battleId` and a `column` for `groupId` to the `Game` table?

Comment: there aren't conditional table constraints. You can however craft a composite FK that involves a Conditional Join. A bit off topic but then again maybe not.

Comment: ok thanks i'll try out composite FK

Comment: @Drew  i you could write an answer i would be happy to except it ;)